# Users with Contribute permission will not be redirected to the friendly url page, when they create a new enterprise wiki page

Tags: navigation, publishing-site, 2016, managed-navigation, enterprise-wiki

I am facing this strange problem inside my sharepoint serve 2016.

1. now i have created a new site collection of type "Publishing">>"Enterprise Wiki".
2. then i leave the navigation setting as is "Managed Navigation" with Friendly urls.
3. i define that the wiki pages requires approval and that only the editor and approves can view pending pages.

but i am facing this strange behavior/problem :-

1. when the site admin or user with approve permission, create a new wiki page and they enter the wiki page name such as "test page 123",then when they save the wiki page they will be redirected to the following friendly url which is fine.

> /sitecollection/test-page-123/

2. while if a contributor user, try to create a new wiki page and they enter the wiki page name such as "test page 1234" , they will be redirected to the non-friendly url such as

> ```
> /sitecollection/page/test-page-1234.aspx
> ```

although the related term will be created , and if the contributor user tried to manually navigate to the friendly url version of the wiki page, then it will be accessible to him `/sitecollection/test-page-1234/`

but why contributor users will be redirected to the non-friendly url when they create a new wiki page, as for approver users ??